# Coffeescript syntax issue with for statement

Tags: if-statement, coffeescript, conditional-statements

Using Coffeescript, I am trying to set conditionals for setting a fillColor on a graph plot for two variables; lastVisibility and curr_visibility. Something is not right with my syntax. Any suggestions

```
for set in datasets
            line.push
                data: set,
                lines:
                    show: true
                    fill: true
                    opacity: 0.7
                    fillColor: if lastVisibilty == 0 & curr_visibility == 0 
                        then "#C90E30"
                    else lastVisibilty == 0 & curr_visibility == 1
                        then "#439C32"
                    else lastVisibilty == 1 & curr_visibility == 0
                        then "#C90E30"
                    else
                        "#439C32"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of problems here:

1. You only use `then` when you're using a one-liner such as `a = if b then c else d`, if you're using the multi-line form of `if` then you don't use `then`s.
2. You have multiple `else` branches where you mean `else if`.
3. `&` and `&&` are different things, `&` is a bit-wise operator, `&&` is the logical conjunction you're looking for.
4. You need to be very careful and consistent with your indentation.

Applying those adjustments to your code you get:

```
for set in datasets
    line.push
        data: set,
        lines:
            show: true
            fill: true
            opacity: 0.7
            fillColor: if lastVisibilty == 0 && curr_visibility == 0 
                "#C90E30"
            else if lastVisibilty == 0 && curr_visibility == 1
                "#439C32"
            else if lastVisibilty == 1 && curr_visibility == 0
                "#C90E30"
            else
                "#439C32"
```

However, the conditional logic inside your loop doesn't depend on `set` (i.e. is loop invariant) so you should factor that out:

```
fillColor = if lastVisibilty == 0 && curr_visibility == 0 
        "#C90E30"
    else if lastVisibilty == 0 && curr_visibility == 1
        "#439C32"
    else if lastVisibilty == 1 && curr_visibility == 0
        "#C90E30"
    else
        "#439C32"
for set in datasets
    line.push
        data: set,
        lines:
            show: true
            fill: true
            opacity: 0.7
            fillColor: fillColor
```

Or better, push all the invariant stuff outside the loop to further clarify the code:

```
fillColor = if lastVisibilty == 0 && curr_visibility == 0 
        "#C90E30"
    else if lastVisibilty == 0 && curr_visibility == 1
        "#439C32"
    else if lastVisibilty == 1 && curr_visibility == 0
        "#C90E30"
    else
        "#439C32"
lines =
    show: true
    fill: true
    opacity: 0.7
    fillColor: fillColor
for set in datasets
    line.push
        data: set,
        lines: lines
```

Or, since a for-loop is an expression, you could say:

```
fillColor = if lastVisibilty == 0 && curr_visibility == 0 
        "#C90E30"
    else if lastVisibilty == 0 && curr_visibility == 1
        "#439C32"
    else if lastVisibilty == 1 && curr_visibility == 0
        "#C90E30"
    else
        "#439C32"
lines =
    show: true
    fill: true
    opacity: 0.7
    fillColor: fillColor
line = ({ data: set, lines: line } for set in datasets)
```

Assuming that `line` is empty before your loop of course; if it isn't then you could use [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
line = line.concat({data: set, lines: line } for set in datasets)
```

to append the loop's data to `line`.

Comment: Your answer was spot on and I have added the fillColor: if conditionals statement outside my original for loop. However, I am now having a new problem caused by the curr_visibility var for one of the conditionals. I'll post that in a separate question.